# Internet not working when lower bandwidth is used, works with higher bandwidth

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, bandwidth

So I will try to explain this as clear as possible.

My internet works just fine when I need to use more than 1M/s for example when watching YouTube,(both my phone, for WiFi, and my pc for Ethernet are tested ), or I could do a speed test on speedtest.net and it peaks at around 100Mbps.

But when i try to do a google search or load up discord it takes like 10 refreshes and around 1 minute to load, and on my phone it shows that the WiFi is not connected to internet.

I use a simple router setup, I have an Innbox F60 and a SFP100B1310-1550:

[image]

I don't know what it is called, but it converts optical signal to internet.

Any ideas for what's causing this?

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

PS: Yes I did reboots and messed around with it a little, didn't change anything

Comment: That doesn't sound like a bandwidth issue. What DNS servers do you have configured on the router? Do you see any packet loss being reported by `ping -4 google.com` and by `ping -6 google.com`?

Comment: Also, the thing is a "fiber optic transceiver" SFP module, a fairly common one for 100 Mbps fiber Ethernet. (There's no "optical to internet", it's the same internet data going over fiber...)

Comment: using [code] ping -4 google.com [/code] yields an error that states that ping request could not find host google.com , the same for -6, using simply [code] ping google.com[/code] results in : [code] Ping statistics for 142.250.180.238:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 31ms, Maximum = 32ms, Average = 31ms[/code]

Comment: And yes i do agree that it isn't a network issue , on my devices i use the dns flare server i think it's called, its 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1

Comment: Also i know the code doesn't show up as code ,i can't figure out how it works in comments, i can't edit it for 5 minutes, because of too many edits.